# System.ArgumentException Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule in IsSitecoreFolderRequest

Tags: security, iis

In my error logs, I often see the error:

`System.ArgumentException Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule in IsSitecoreFolderRequest`

The request paths seem to always contain `OpenAccessDataProvider`. For example:

`/news/2019/07/[documents|OpenAccessDataProvider]0590292e-7308-60d3-8844-ff00003e4f20`

The referrer request header always seems to originate from a legitimate path (page) on my site; in fact, the URLs were added by content authors in a rich text field.

What are these requests, and how should I handle them?

Comment: This URL format with `OpenAccessDataProvider` seems to be used on Sitefinity websites.  Do you know if this content was imported into Rich Text fields from a previous website or content authors are copying it from somewhere?

Comment: That's a good point, @AnnaGevel. It is probably a relic from Sitefinity, in which case this becomes a task of data cleanup and content author education, as well as handling for characters such as `[`/`]`/`|` somewhere in my stack.

Comment: Yes, some cleanup and/or potentially redirection is needed depending on where these links should point. I guess even if there was no exception, these links would probably return 404 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anna Gauvel correctly pointed out that these paths were relics from a legacy CMS.

The learnings are:

- Monitor your error logs for errors such as `System.ArgumentException Sitecore.Web.XFrameOptionsHeaderModule in IsSitecoreFolderRequest - illegal characters in path`
- Analyze those requests' `referrer` header to see where the requests might be coming from
- Some of the requests may be originating from your own site, which calls for one or more of the following actions:

  - Better data cleanup detection / controls when migrating content
  - Ongoing content scanning / cleanup
  - Content entry training (especially when pasting in rich text fields, which is a perennial problem)
  - Setting up redirects
  - Performing regular broken link checking